# Should I use HTTP Status code 410 for removed stock on a web site?

Tags: php, seo, http-status-codes

I'm building a site for a motorcycle dealer, and their used stock changes daily. Currently, when stock is removed, Google Webmaster tools sees Error 404, which I should imagine would damage the reputation of the site with Google.

After doing some research, I found that HTTP status 410 means 'gone permanently'. Should I be using this status code for requests to bikes which are no longer in stock? The page gives a message to say that the bike has been sold, and shows a list of other used stock, just wondering what the correct way of handling these would be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My answer is No. I think, you should make a page that says a message about the out-of-stock bikes. Something like error handler.

Comment: Just wondering, why would it damage the reputation of the site with Google? In what way?

Comment: I agree with @BhavikShah . Make a page for out-of-stock bikes.

Comment: out of question : which language are you using?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Google wants to direct users to pages that are likely to be there. If the crawler repeatedly gets 404 errors, it will assume that the site is unstable, and prefer domains that do not return those errors.

Comment: @BhavikShah are you saying returna valid page instead. Wouldn;t that mean Google will send people to a product that no longer exists, forver.

Comment: @Blowski where do you get your information that 404s have a negative impact on a website. I typically hear Googlers saying the opposite.

Comment: @Tiggerito As always, it depends. [This page](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-should-you-handle-expired-content) has a nice discussion of the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The status code should refer to the representation of the resource, not the availability of the resource itself. So a page listing an item that is no longer available should still return a 200 status, not 404 or 410.

Then you can list a message on the page saying 'this item is no longer available'. This is similar to how [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ACE-Jimmy-Savile-Costume/dp/B0096PVYO6) and [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/GERRY-WEBER-top-size-16-BNWOT-/281063500312?pt=UK_Women_s_Tops_Shirts) handle this problem.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's thoughts on this, really appreciate the comments

Comment: furthermore, 410 means the page is not coming back, so when it you restock it, you will have more problems getting it indexed.

Comment: So every product ever sold on ebay still has a valid page, even after it was sold? I can understand using 200 if the product is out of stock, but not if it has gone forever.

Comment: @Tiggerito The status code of the product is not the same as the status code of the representation of the product. When the product is no longer available for purchase, the representation of the product is still available for access. There's value in leaving the record of the product on the internet, both to the business and to users.

Comment: @Blowski I can understand a few cases where keeping old products in the index can be beneficial. Say for Dell who support old products. Or if you want to capture people looking for products you don't sell. But in most cases I would 301 them and not clog up my indexed website with stuff .